# JPA Persist Relationships

Tags: hibernate, jpa

If I have the following Entity object which has several foreign key relationships how do I handle form submission when I don't get the relationship object back in the request.

The entity might look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "middle_name")
private String middleName;

@Column(name = "login_id")
private String loginId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
private Department department;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "employment_type_id")
private EmploymentType employmentType;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "citizenship_id")
private Citizenship citizenship;

public Employee() {
}
}
```

But this is the HTTP POST request I'll be receiving.

```
id: 1
firstName: Bob
lastName: Dole
middleName: Trump
loginId: bdole
departmentId: 1
employmentTypeId: 2
citizenship_id: 4
```

JPA wants to save the relationship object, not the ID. However doing all those look ups also seems inefficient, turning the IDs into the required objects to persist. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Have you thought  of mapping the foreign key as a basic mapping instead of making it a reference mapping?  If your application doesn't need to fetch and pass around the full department, employmentType and citizenship, why burden your application with it in the object model?  Chances are though you will need to perform looksups to make sure those ids exist, otherwise your post can give you non-existing department numbers, so you may have to do the look up anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use getReference 
    http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29

It calls the entityManager to load customer object using the id and then set that onto the customer history. In most cases this call would return a proxy with just the id embedded.

```
Department department = entityManager.getReference(Department.class, departmentId);

Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setDepartment(department);
```